# More Issues Opening Window WPF

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I'm using VB.net and WPF 4.

I cannot seem to open a new window in WPF consistantly. It will work one time, and then the next time I execute the same script, it throws the following exception:

XAMLParseException occured 'Provide value on 'System.Windows.Baml2006.TypeConverterMarkupExtension' threw an exception.' Line number '4' and line position '208'. {Cannot evaluate expression because the code of the current method is optimized.}

Here is the script:

```
Dim Window As Window = New GAME_WINDOW
Window.Show()
```

Yes, "GAME_WINDOW" is a legitimate WPF window. Here are the first four lines of XAML code for the window I'm trying to open:

```
 <Window x:Class="GAME_WINDOW"
     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
     Title="Operation SpyRat: Word4Word" Icon="/VBP-WORD4WORD;component/alicia.ico" WindowState="Maximized" Background="Black" xmlns:my="clr-namespace:VBP_WORD4WORD">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the problem is the window Icon specification in the XAML.  Try removing the Icon="..." from your XAML, and see if it corrects the issue.

If so, you'll need to make sure this is specified in proper [Pack URI format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx).  Most likely, this would be:

```
Icon="pack://application:,,,/component/alicia.ico"
```